# Client.guilds.get() not working as intended

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was writing a Discord bot for my friend, and when I was making a rainbow color role feature for him, I stopped on a big error.

First of all, this is my code:

```
var guild = client.guilds.get("493432486148177923")
var role = guild.roles.get("501752627709870080");
var role2 = guild.roles.get("493436150019784704");
setInterval(() => {
  role.setColor([Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)])
  role2.setColor([Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)])
}, 8000)
```

All stopped on the `guild` variable. It was giving out me null/undefined, and when going to `guild.roles.get()`, it caused my program to crash. I tried using `.find()` instead of `.get()` for finding the guild, but this also didn't work.

Comment: You're using the method correctly. The only thing you can do is checking the guild ID. Please note that the bot needs to be in the guild for it to work.

Comment: It is in the guild.

Comment: Are you sure the ID is the right one? How did you get it?

Comment: Right click on the guild and copy ID

Comment: Try using `console.log(client.guilds.keyArray())` and tell my what you get

Comment: Array[0], it's inside a server tho

Comment: That's really weird. Try to kick the bot and then making it join again. Also, try updating the library

Comment: I kicked it out and invited again, but this didn't help at all. I also updated the library and it didn't work either.

Comment: Does `console.log(client.guilds.keyArray())` still log the same? You're using `discord.js` installed through npm, right?

Comment: Yes, still Array[0]

Comment: Does `console.log(client.guilds.first())` log `undefined`?

Comment: Yes, but bot detects messages from a guild

Comment: That is definitely something that's not supposed to happen. There's no apparent reason for that Collection to be empty, so please open a issue on the GitHub page of the library: [link here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues). The developers will try to help you

Comment: 2 Things - 1. Rainbow roles are against TOS 2. If you are attempting this outside of a command or an event, the guild will return undefined.

Answer (score 16):

I don't know if you are still searching for an answer but I just encountered the same problem. After a bit of investigation I came up with a solution:

```
var server = client.guilds.cache.get(serverID);
```

This works for me. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a reason as to *why* that happens, but the current method I'm using is this:

```
var g = client.guilds.get("GUILD-ID");
var c = g.channels.get("CHANNEL-ID");
```

Or in one line:

```
var c = client.guilds.get("GUILD-ID").channels.get("CHANNEL-ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js v13

This works as `Client.guilds.get()`:

```
var guild = undefined;
client.guilds.cache.forEach(g => { //Every guild
    if (g.id === "493432486148177923") { //Verify the guild's ID
        return guild = c;
    }
})

//If guild doesn't exist: guild = undefined
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).